# Получить результат Laravel Query Builder как Json

Tags: php, laravel

Есть ли способ получить результат Query Builde сразу в формате Json, а не collection?
Я знаю, что можно использовать `$collection->toJson()`или `json_encode()`, но их использование занимает слишком много времени при большой выборки данных.

Comment: Уточните, что имеется в виду под "использование занимает слишком много времени"? Обработка в браузере? Время скачивания? Обработка в скрипте (тогда зачем переводить в json?)?

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Быстрее нативной json_encode Вы ничего не получите...

Comment: @TotalPusher, обработка на стороне сервера занимает много времени. Json я хотел получить, что бы передать его в браузер и далее выводить эти данные через JQuery.  Рендерить страницу на сервере, тоже не вариант, так как тоже занимает достаточно много времени.

Comment: Сократите объем данных. 1. Можно выбирать не все поля, а только необходимые. 2. Можно использовать пагинацию/лимиты. 3. При передаче внутри скрипта нет никакой необходимости преобразовывать в JSON. Можно использовать cursor, а после обработки - финальное кодирование в JSON. Уточните более конкретно, с примерами кода, иначе задача очень общая и вам тут не помогут

Comment: @TotalPusher, пагинация - это именно то, что мне нужно, но о чём я не подумал из-за нехватки опыта. Спасибо, что подсказали.